# What were templars looking for in Jerusalem in Da Vinci Code?

Tags: the-da-vinci-code

In Da Vinci Code movie, it is explained that the Templars, formed by the Priory of Sion, wanted to take Jerusalem to find the Holy Grail, and apparently found it there (since they stopped searching afterwards and gained huge power).

Since it is afterwards revealed that they have been protecting both Mary Magdalena's sarcophagus and descendants in France or England since way before that, what were they looking for in Jerusalem ?

Comment: Long time since I saw or read it - I have a vague recollection we were supposed to think they were looking for a cup, but we don't find out what they were really there for until the big reveal, much later.

Comment: Yes, that's it. But in the "big reveal" we learn that the priory of sion has been protecting the "real" grail since the beginning

Comment: I can't remember it accurately enough for an answer. Hope someone can fill in the details properly.

Comment: The last time I watched the movie, I did not come away with the "big reveal" being that the Templars had protected Mary since "the beginning." The Templars were founded in 1118 c.e., so "the beginning" is very relative. The movie used as a plot element that they came away from jerusalem with something important, something that made them suddenly powerful. I believe that the movie's premise is that what they found was Mary's sarcophagus (and maybe some wisdom). I suspect that you're reading into the movie something that didn't actually occur, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: I may have indeed misunderstood, but I think when they explain that Mary Magdalena moved to France, the Priory of Sion protected her there from the start, but I could be wrong indeed. Maybe it's her descendants that remained in Jerusalem and that were found by the Templars, I don't know.